# How to deploy dash generated html output to vercel?

Tags: html, http-status-code-404, plotly-dash, vercel

I am trying to deploy python-dash generated html on vercel  [image]

The git repo has two files .json and .html in the same directory. After importing I click deploy on vercel and get a 404. The .json file:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [{
      "src": "./LOS021123LATE.html",
      "use": "@vercel/static"
    }],
    "routes": [{"handle": "filesystem"},
      {
        "src": "/.*",
        "dest": "/"
      }
    ]
  }
```